# What is the location (skydrive) of an opened online office 365 document?

Tags: office365, onedrive

I know that for normal office desktop application you can know where the application is located by going into the file Tab like as the tutorial said.

https://images.tips.net/S06/Figs/T4869F2.png

How about online office files opened in browser, how do i know what is the location of the file?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For office 365 you can click on the top link, then the location is shown.

[image]

Answer (score 1):

They're either stored on a OneDrive virtual folder or on a SharePoint "folder" (directory, more like), but in both cases, they're in the cloud, and linked to a specific account.

You need credentials and/or permissions to access them (in the case of a SharePoint folder).

You can download a local copy of a document for ease of use if you want to edit it with your local Word or Excel, then upload it back into the cloud if you want. If the document is shared with others, and they too need to edit it while you are doing that on your PC, there might be data corruption, though.

Those documents are meant to be created, edited, saved and shared online.

Comment: I know it is being saved in OneDrive. I meant I want to know the specific one drive folder, where the file is stored.

Comment: If you meant by that the physical location of the exact Azure (most probably) server where your virtual drive is hosted, then I'm afraid I don't have the answer. Microsoft probably doesn't either. Office 365 isn't devised to provide that kind of information to end-users.

Comment: OneDrive is organized by folders right? I am asking how to know what directory a document is in. In Google Apps, for example a Sheet is located in the google drive, you ca check the location via the Version History, which is gone now. But there is an icon of directory on top of name. Does the office 365 also have such feature?